# Filtering a column with multiple options in a grid Ext JS 6.0.2

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm facing a problem with a filtering column in a ExtJS grid. I'm kinda new with this technology so I'm not 100% there on understanding it. As you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abottoni/6wKSG/10/

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
  Ext.define('Project', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [{
      name: 'name'
    }, {
      name: 'client'
    }, {
      name: 'domain'
    }] ... See the Fiddle in the Link
```

I'm showing a grid with 3 columns. The 2nd column (Client), is the one giving me problems. Some of the rows in the grid have 2 options in the column (Using a comma for separation), so when I click on the column's menu and get into filters, I'm having all the options (even the ones with the comma separated values). I don't want to have them, as I just want to show unique options, so when I click in one of them (like for example Client A), I will filter not only the rows with Client A as a value in the column, but also the one that has Client A, Client B.

For the fiddle I have control of the options, but in my real project, I'm getting the data from the Database.

Is there a way to make this to work the way I'm explaining?

NOTE: I'm using 'gridfilters' plugin

Thanks in advance for all the input you can give me with this.